# Programa não executa os dois laços For dentro do if - C

Tags: c, c++, algoritmo, lógica

Possuo 2 laços *for* dentro de um *if*, como mostrado a seguir:

```
              if (grid[j][k] == words[i][0]){ 
                    int el = j, col = k;
                    //Metodo direita, baixo
                    for(l=0;l < wordlen(search_word);l++){
                        if(l%2 != 0 ){
                            // Procura à direita
                            if(words[i][l] == grid[el][col]) {
                                matched[el][col] = 1;
                                col++;
                                if(words[i][l+1]=='\0') {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Procura à baixo
                            if(words[i][l] == grid[el][col]) {
                                matched[el][col] = 1;
                                el++;
                                if(words[i][l+1]=='\0') {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //Metodo baixo, direita
                    for(l=0;l < wordlen(search_word);l++){
                        if(l%2 == 0){
                            // Procura à direita
                            if(words[i][l] == grid[el][col]) {
                                matched[el][col] = 1;
                                col++;
                                if(words[i][l+1]=='\0') {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Procura à baixo
                            if(words[i][l] == grid[el][col]) {
                                matched[el][col] = 1;
                                el++;
                                if(words[i][l+1]=='\0') {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }
```

A intenção seria que ele percorresse os 2 laços, porém ele só executa o primeiro. Alguém sabe o porquê?

Comment: Crie um [mcve] para assim alguém te ajudar, pois não tem como testar seu código.